# change hover color of shop by categories in magento

Tags: css

if you see at left of the site , there is a "BROWSE BY",  under that list of categories are displayed :

for example "Action & toy figures". if we hover on "Action & toy figures", its color should change to black

how to change hover color of the category.

let me know if you have any clarifications.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS with inspect element

i can suggest you to add in your css

```
.block-layered-nav dd li a:hover {color:#000}
```

which is currently as below in your css

```
 .block-layered-nav dd li a:hover {color:#02B0D2}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add

```
.block-layered-nav dd li a:hover{color:#000 !important}
```

To the File "styles.css".
The File YOu can locate under directory
"/skin/frontend/default/em0113/css/styles.css"

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to add special class to each li in the list.

In /template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml

replace the foreach with this:

```
<?php $i; foreach ($_categories as $_category): $i++; ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li clas="colour0<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?>
                            <span class="count">(<?php echo $_category->getProductCount() ?>)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
```

What I did is adding a new class to each LI which you can rename to whatever you would like and in your css you need to add colour to each class:

```
.colour01:hover {background:#000}
.colour02:hover {background:#fff}
```

Comment: you are welcome, did it work? i didn't try it myself :)

Comment: no, i will try and tell you soon....

Comment: no problem I only think this is the best solution as you can colour each item on the list, let me know your feedback please. is good to know anyway